# NullPointerException при отправке запроса к бд

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Подскажите пожалуйста, при попытке отправки запроса:

```
 public List<Answer> findAllAnswersForQuestion(int id) {
            Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            String hql = "FROM Answer WHERE Answer.question.id = :id";
            Query<Answer> query = session.createQuery(hql, Answer.class).setParameter("id", id);
            return query.list();
}
```

Получаю ошибку в строке Query query = session.createQuery(hql, Answer.class).setParameter("id", id);

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1192)
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1186)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:376)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:345)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:659)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5002)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExprLhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5614)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4987)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1286)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4174)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2138)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:815)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:609)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:104)
    at com.quiz2.services.UserService.findAllAnswersForQuestion(UserService.java:73)
    at com.quiz2.services.Service.findAllAnswersForQuestion(Service.java:44)
    at com.quiz2.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Класс вопросов

```
package com.quiz2.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "text_question")
    private String text_question;
    @Column(name = "score")
    private int score;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Answer> answers;

    public Question() {
    }

    public Question(String text_question, int score) {
        this.text_question = text_question;
        this.score = score;
        this.answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
    }

    public void addAnswer(Answer answer, boolean correct) {
        answer.setCorrect(correct);
        answer.setQuestion(this);
        answers.add(answer);
    }

    public void removeAnswer(Answer answer) {
        answers.remove(answer);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getText_question() {
        return text_question;
    }

    public void setText_question(String text_question) {
        this.text_question = text_question;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question: " + getText_question();
    }
}
```

Класс ответов

```
package com.quiz2.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "answers")
public class Answer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "text_answer")
    private String text_answer;
    @Column(name = "correct")
    private boolean correct;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;

    public Answer() {
    }

    public Answer(String text_answer) {
        this.text_answer = text_answer;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getText_answer() {
        return text_answer;
    }

    public void setText_answer(String text_answer) {
        this.text_answer = text_answer;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return correct;
    }

    public void setCorrect(boolean correct) {
        this.correct = correct;
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID " + getId() + " Answer " + getText_answer() + " correct: " + isCorrect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по трассе, ошибка в запросе. Вот точно [такой же случай](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47115030/1911548).

Comment: @sergey Спасибо, я идиот, но с Вашей помощью справился. 
        String hql = "SELECT a FROM Answer as a WHERE a.question.id = :id";